# Responsive with Metro-UI-CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, microsoft-metro

I am using Metro-UI-CSS and I am stuck with a problem and need help. Please See blow Images. Also I want to know that can I use JQuery 1 and 2 in same page.

```
<body class="metro">
<div style="padding: 10px 0;" class="container">
  <div style="padding: 10px 0;" class="container">
    <div class="grid no-margin">
      <div class="row no-margin">
       <div class="span6">
       <div class="span3 bg-amber padding10">
          <h3 style="padding:0 0 20px 10px; font-size:1.2em" class="border-bottom fg-white">Company Infomation</h3>
        </div>

       <div class="span3 bg-red padding10">
          <h3 style="padding:0 0 20px 10px; font-size:1.2em" class="border-bottom fg-white">Latest Travel News</h3>
        </div>

       <div class="span3 bg-lighterBlue padding10">
          <h3 style="padding:0 0 20px 10px; font-size:1.2em" class="border-bottom fg-white">Book with Confidence</h3>
        </div>

       <div class="span3 bg-pink padding10">
          <h3 style="padding:0 0 20px 10px; font-size:1.2em" class="border-bottom fg-white">Quick links</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span6">
        <div class="padding10 bg-orange">
        <h3 style="padding:0 0 20px 10px; font-size:1.2em" class="border-bottom fg-white">
        Cheapest Flight Tickets for Worldwide Destinations</h3>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Current View:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxISt.png

I need this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nlbh.png

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after much fiddling, here is your outcome.

Basically you are making a large grid with 1 row. In a span6 (left side) you are making another grid with two rows and hence 4 buttons.

The other span6 (right side) is for the large orange div that has a width equal to the height of the left hand side's two rows.

Hope that's clear

```
<body class="metro">
<div style="padding: 10px 0;" class="container">
    <div class="grid no-margin">
        <div class="row no-margin">
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="grid no-margin">
                    <div class="row no-margin">
                        <div class="span3 bg-amber padding10">
                          <h3 style="padding:0 0 20px 10px; font-size:1.2em" class="border-bottom fg-white">Company Infomation</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="span3 bg-red padding10">
                          <h3 style="padding:0 0 20px 10px; font-size:1.2em" class="border-bottom fg-white">Latest Travel News</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row no-margin" style="padding:10px 0">
                        <div class="span3 bg-lighterBlue padding10">
                          <h3 style="padding:0 0 20px 10px; font-size:1.2em" class="border-bottom fg-white">Book with Confidence</h3>
                        </div>

                       <div class="span3 bg-pink padding10">
                          <h3 style="padding:0 0 20px 10px; font-size:1.2em" class="border-bottom fg-white">Quick links</h3>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="grid no-margin">
                    <div class="row no-margin">
                        <div class="span6 padding10 bg-orange" style="height:180px">
                            <h3 style="padding:0 0 20px 10px; font-size:1.2em; " class="border-bottom fg-white">Cheapest Flight Tickets for Worldwide Destinations</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide a fiddler? I never heard of that CSS responsive framework.. I would make three columns, 33%, 33%, 66%..
float them left (and clear it).
In each column I would then place my color divs. On the third column since it is one div I would set a static height to make sure the size stays the same cross browser. Than I would play with the margins to make sure everything is even.